# Wrong value injected with Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I have two properties files:

```
prop1.properties:
prop1.sample=value123
```

and

```
prop2.properties:
prop2.sample=value234
```

When I inject these properties values two my "InjectValues" bean then everything works in a proper way. But when I want to inject a value from one PropertyPlaceHolder to another class which simply extends PropertyPlaceHolder then instead of value, the key is inserted as presented below.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:C:\test\prop1.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurerNew"
    class="com.test.spring.property.EncryptedPlaceHolder">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:C:\test\prop2.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="${prop1.sample}" /> <!-- Value "${prop1.sample}" is injected instead of value123 -->
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="#[" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]" />
</bean>

<bean id="injectValues"
    class="com.test.spring.property.InjectValues">
    <property name="value1" value="${prop1.sample}" /> <!-- Correct value "value123" is injected -->
    <property name="value2" value="#[prop2.sample]" /> <!-- Correct value "value234" is injected -->
</bean>
```

Comment: PropertyPlaceHolders don't replace placeholders in other PropertyPlaceHolders. They don't operate sequentially and are all executed in the same phase (and are all already constructed before that). So it will simply not work.

Comment: Can I somehow force container to move one of PropertyPlaceHolder execution to another phase?

Comment: The property placeholder is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which executes at a pre determined time. You might be able to hack around it by loading a context fully, adding the bean definition and reload the context but that would be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that PropertyPlaceHolders can't replace placeholders in other PropertyPlaceHolders because are executed in the same phase as mentioned in the comments.